# How to expand a compressed list into a full list in Python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have a compressed list like (and possibly bigger):

```
[[[1, [2, 3], [3, 2]]], [[2, [1, 3], [3, 1]]], [[3, [1, 2], [2, 1]]]]
```

What can I do to expand it to a complete list like?

```
[[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [3,1,2], [2,3,1], [3,2,1]]
```

I think this is some sort of recursion but I don't know how. 
Thank you in advance

edit: Here's a function I wrote for it already but it keeps saying syntax error.

```
def expandList(aList):
    """expand a list"""

    finalList = []

    for j in aList:

        if type(j) != type(list):
            tempList = []
            tempList.append(j)

            finalList.append(tempList)

        else:
            finalList.extend(expandList(j))

    return finalList
```

Edit: Whoops, I meant:

```
[[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1]]
```

not:

```
[[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [3,1,2], [2,3,1], [3,2,1]]
```

Sorry for any confusions.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got to the output from input?

Comment: I thought I had a handle on what you wanted but your output isn't quite in the order I expected. Please do expand on what you're trying to do.

Comment: And why does each sublist contain a single nested sublist?

Comment: I think the OP meant to have: 
[[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2], [3,2,1]]

Comment: Your data structure is very heavily suboptimal.

Comment: Please tell us what version of Python you're running.  I only have CPython 2.6.4 and 3.1.2 handy, and neither finds a syntax error in the code you posted.  So either your Python is even more outdated than mine, or the syntax error is in some other code you haven't shown us, or this isn't the code you're actually running.  Also, please post the _full_ stacktrace... and take the time to read it yourself, since it will tell you almost exactly where the syntax error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this,

```
l = [[[1, [2, 3], [3, 2]]], [[2, [1, 3], [3, 1]]], [[3, [1, 2], [2, 1]]]]
final_list = []
for k in l:
    for x in k:
        t = [x[0]]
        t.extend([i for i in x[1]])
        final_list.append(t)
        t = [x[0]]
        t.extend([i for i in x[2]])
        final_list.append(t)
print (final_list)
```

This yields,

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Instead of `[i for i in x[1]]`, have you tried simply `x[1]` (for `x[2]` as well)? It looks like it's already a `list`, so you shouldn't have to generate a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the exact input structure you listed, with redundant `list`s:

```
big = [[[1, [2, 3], [3, 2]]], [[2, [1, 3], [3, 1]]], [[3, [1, 2], [2, 1]]]]
>>> [[a]+i for useless in big for a, *b in useless for i in b]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Assuming a cleaner input structure without redundant `list`s:

```
>>> big = [[1, [2, 3], [3, 2]], [2, [1, 3], [3, 1]], [3, [1, 2], [2, 1]]]
>>> [[a]+i for a, *b in big for i in b]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```